Next -14 : DYNAMIC_SERVER_USAGE
I am working on a Next 14 project to familiarize myself with all the latest updates.
I created a simple posts page that fetches  a post by ID and renders the post. I am also using generateStaticParams to generate all the post pages during build time. The application is working correctly on local environment. The build is also running and running next start on my local environment is also working as expected.
However, after deployment on Vercel, the application breaks when I visit the post page. Vercel logs display the following error: DYNAMIC_SERVER_USAGE
The code for the page is:
import Comments from "@/app/components/Comments";
import CommentsInput from "@/app/components/CommentsInput";
import MarkdownRenderer from "@/app/components/MarkdownRenderer";
import { prisma } from "@/lib/prisma";
import { authOptions } from "@/utils/authOptions";
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import Link from "next/link";
import React, { cache } from "react";

import "react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css";

import { ArrowLeftIcon, PencilSquareIcon } from "@heroicons/react/24/outline";
import { Comment, Post } from "@prisma/client";

export type CommentsWithCommenterInfo = (Comment & {
  commenter: { name: string; id: string };
})[];
type PostWithComments = ({ comments: CommentsWithCommenterInfo } & Post) | null;

const getPost = cache(async (id: string): Promise<PostWithComments | null> => {
  return prisma.post.findFirst({
    where: { id },
    include: {
      comments: {
        include: {
          commenter: {
            select: {
              name: true,
              id: true,
            },
          },
        },
        orderBy: {
          createdAt: "desc",
        },
      },
    },
  });
});

export async function generateStaticParams() {
  const posts = await prisma.post.findMany({
    select: {
      id: true,
    },
  });

  return posts.map((post) => ({ id: post.id }));
}

export async function generateMetadata({ params }: { params: { id: string } }) {
  const post = await getPost(params.id);
  return {
    title: post?.title || "Next Posts",
  };
}
const PostPage = async ({ params }: { params: { id: string } }) => {
  const post = await getPost(params.id);
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);
  if (!post) return <div>Post Not Found</div>;

  return (
    <div className="px-4">
      <Link href="/">
        <ArrowLeftIcon className="h-5 mb-4" />
      </Link>
      <div className="flex w-full justify-between items-start">
        <h1 className="text-4xl mb-4 font-semibold max-w-6xl">{post.title}</h1>
        {session?.user?.id === post.authorId && (
          <Link href={`/post/${post.id}/edit`}>
            <PencilSquareIcon className="h-6" />
          </Link>
        )}
      </div>
      <MarkdownRenderer content={post.content} />
      <div className="mt-10" />
      <CommentsInput postId={post.id} />
      <h6 className="mb-6 text-xl">Comments</h6>

      <Comments
        comments={post.comments}
        isPostAuthor={!!(session && post.authorId === session?.user.id)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default PostPage;

Also sharing a screenshot of the error on Vercel.

Am I using generateStaticParams incorrectly here? I found it used in a similar manner in the official Next.js docs
